# C++ system() function — How to collect the output of the issued command?

Tags: c++, popen

I'm running some commands with the C++ `system()` function:

```
int system ( const char * command );
```

How can I collect the standard output from the issued commands?

To be specific, I want to collect the output of the issued command (for example, the directory listing output from issuing the `dir` command).

Comment: I think he means the string returned by the comment, i.e., stdout.

Comment: yes, I mean the string returned by the issued command

Comment: Note that the `system()` function (and the `popen()` and `pclose()` functions suggested in the accepted answer) are also applicable to C.  I've not dual-tagged this question (it generally isn't a good idea to dual-tag with C and C++), but this might be an exception to the rule.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you looking for returned value (as in "exit status") of the executed command, or for its output (as in "what did it print")?

If the latter, use [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) and [`pclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pclose.html) instead.

If the former, look at the return value from `system()` (and use the documentation for [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) to interpret it).

Comment: Thank you for the hint - I will try with popen()

Comment: Isn't system just a passthru call in the sense that stdout/stderr are passed through to the paren't stdout/stderr?

Comment: @David: yes, but the OP doesn't want it to be passed through. he wants to collect it in a string in his program

Answer (score 8):

`system()` returns an `int`, so just grab it: `int rvalue = system(command);`

I believe the exact details of what system() will return are system-specific, though.

Comment: They are indeed : 

7.20.4.6 The system function :
If the argument is a null pointer, the system function returns nonzero only if a
command processor is available. If the argument is not a null pointer, and the system
function does return, it returns an implementation-defined value

Comment: I don't need the retrun value of system() - I want to collect the return string of the issued command...

Comment: What do you think system returns? It returns the return value of the command.

Comment: I know, that system() returns an "int". Therfore I asked if there is a way to collect the return value of the issued command.

Comment: The value of that int IS the return value of the command.  Perhaps you mean you want to collect the output to one of the streams like stdout?

Comment: @mspoerr: I think you need to explain "return value of the issued command", since you seem to use "return value" in an unconventional way (if it is *not* the int that you are after). If you really don't know how to store an int in a variable, we have an even deeper problem communicating.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by bmorin's attempt, but working and tested, this snippet will take a char* command and return a char* containing the results of executing that command...

```
// Calling function must free the returned result.
char* exec(const char* command) {
  FILE* fp;
  char* line = NULL;
  // Following initialization is equivalent to char* result = ""; and just
  // initializes result to an empty string, only it works with
  // -Werror=write-strings and is so much less clear.
  char* result = (char*) calloc(1, 1);
  size_t len = 0;

  fflush(NULL);
  fp = popen(command, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot execute command:\n%s\n", command);
    return NULL;
  }

  while(getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1) {
    // +1 below to allow room for null terminator.
    result = (char*) realloc(result, strlen(result) + strlen(line) + 1);
    // +1 below so we copy the final null terminator.
    strncpy(result + strlen(result), line, strlen(line) + 1);
    free(line);
    line = NULL;
  }

  fflush(fp);
  if (pclose(fp) != 0) {
    perror("Cannot close stream.\n");
  }
  return result;
}
```

I looked into just editing bmorin's code, but would have had to change most lines, so a separate answer seemed more appropriate.  Apologies if not.  (Amongst other problems, bmorin's code didn't actually accumulate the lines; it printed them to stdout, where I presume they would not be wanted, since system() would have done that; and it returned void in one error path, when the function must return a char*, so the code wouldn't compile.  Perhaps most egregious, it freed the result just before returning it.)

Answer (score 3):

There are typically two ways for a system program to "return" a value: by writing to stdout, and by returning a status integer at the end of the program. (there are often more ways to return results, eg. by writing to a file or into a database, but I assume those are out of scope here).

For receiving the status code, just check the return value of the `system` function.

For receiving the output, either redirect it into a file, and read the file afterwards, or use `popen`.

Answer (score 3):

The return value of `system` is (ironically) system-dependent, but in POSIX systems (including Linux, etc), it's the same as for [wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) -- low 8 or 16 bits are the exit status of the child (probably what you mean by "value returned by"), higher bits indicating what kind of signal terminated the child, if any.  The URL to the manpage I've given supplies the preprocessor macros you can use to pry apart that return value!

There is no such thing as a "return string" of a program, as you've now clarified in a comment is what you desire; as another answer already mentioned, if you want the text which gets *output* by the other program, you should use `popen` instead of `system`.

Answer (score 0):

[system()](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Running-a-Command) is declared and defined in [libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/). You can either read the first link I provided, or do `man system` at a command prompt in your shell.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the popen() functions, as said by other people as well,
but this problem is platform specific. the popen() function is 
available on operating systems that use the POSIX API. I am not
sure if this command would work on other APIs like WIN32

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet (in plain C) executing a command with `popen` and returning its output:

```
char* exec(const char* command) {
    FILE* fp;
    char* result = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    fflush(NULL);
    fp = popen(command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot execute command:\n%s\n", command);
        return;
    }

    while(getline(&result, &len, fp) != -1) {
        fputs(result, stdout);
    }

    free(result);
    fflush(fp);
    if (pclose(fp) != 0) {
        perror("Cannot close stream.\n");
    }
    return result;
}
```