# How to get curl output in a variable ?

Tags: c, variables, curl, terminal

Showing snippet of c code.

```
char command[]="curl -X POST -d \'{\"device_id\": \"2204\"}' http://example.com/configure";
    .
    .
    system(command);
    .
    .
```

Now this gives the output in terminal. I want to get this output in variable.. How should i acheive that ?

Comment: Although the duplicate question is tagged with [tag:c++], the answer actually applies equally to C.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Thank you.. Its helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure it's been answered here.

```
popen(3)
```

[C++ system() function — How to collect the output of the issued command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583234/c-system-function-how-to-collect-the-return-value-of-the-issued-command)