# Why there is difference in curl outputs?

Tags: curl, response, popen

the code snippet given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583234/c-system-function-how-to-collect-the-output-of-the-issued-command) gives me the output as

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    56    0    32  100    24    461    346 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   463
{"success": true}
```

but when i give the same curl command directly in the terminal it gives me output as

```
{"success": true}
```

only.

So why there is difference between these outputs? I just want the response i.e. {"success": true} here. I don't want rest of the data. How should i do that ?

Curl full command which i was using is: curl -X POST -d '{"device_id": "181CBBE"}' http://www.example.com/get_device_details

Comment: this is the summary of the `CURL`. it shows you how output generated

Comment: @absfrm yeah that's fine. but why there is the difference between the outputs given by "popen" form the program and the one given when i directly give the same curl command in console ?

Comment: It depends on the scripts backend. And could please post your `CURL` full command for it?(with example url)

Comment: @absfrm : here is my full command.
curl -X POST -d '{"device_id": "181CBBE"}' http://example.com/get_device_details/

And for that program snippet, i am storing this whole command in one string and passing its address in popen.

Comment: have you tried `curl -s` within your command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the summary goes to `stderr` and the response goes to `stdout`; your `popen` command only returns `stdout`; use `curl -s` to suppress the summary