# getting values with system() in C

Tags: c, system

I want to collect values to a array in C using system().

With:

```
hcidump -a | egrep 'RSSI|bdaddr' | grep -A1 --no-group-separator 'bdaddr 78:A5:04:17:9F:66' | grep -Po 'RSSI:\s+\K.*'
```

an output like that:

```
-25
-24
-23
-26
-26
```

and want to store that values in an array in C, but that's not possible, I assume, with:

```
system("hcidump -a | egrep 'RSSI|bdaddr' | grep -A1 --no-group-separator 'bdaddr 78:A5:04:17:9F:66' | grep -Po 'RSSI:\s+\K.*'");
```

Has anybody an idea if there is a command to achieve that? or a workaroung?
My only idea is to write the data into a file and afterwards read the information out of it, but I would like to have a better approch.

Best regards Adrian

Comment: Read about [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

Comment: `popen()` is the tool of choice here, agreed. `system()` will not lead you anywhere, you have no direct access to the program output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583234/c-system-function-how-to-collect-the-output-of-the-issued-command

Answer (score 2):

Use the [link](http://theunixshell.blogspot.se/2013/01/executing-shell-command-in-cc-and.html)  and execute the command and inside the while loop, store each and every line in the array. Your job is done.